# How to finish my modal ajax code to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<?php foreach (range(0, 29) as $rs) { ?>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-href="rsc1<?php echo $rs;?>" class="link">rsc1<?php echo $rs;?></a><br/>
<?php } ?>

<div id="dialog-modal"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.link').on('click','a[data-toggle="modal"]',function(e){
var linkValue = $(this).attr('data-href');

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'details.php',
    data: 'i=' + linkValue,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#dialog-modal').html(data).dialog();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}); });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$i = $_GET['i'];
echo $i;  ?>
```

How to make url open in modal dialog? Please show me a demo with my this functions. I need a css maybe and some html code.
Ah, also I am using this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: After correcting your code as @cubitouch has suggested, If it still doesn't work, make sure you add the script anywhere after the markup `<div id="dialog-modal"></div>` or attach the script to an on load event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a working solution for you
I have commented the php code there and using the java script values. But I hope it will help you.

[DEMO][http://jsfiddle.net/gdVLs/]

Comment: there is another bad thing.. For example, I wanna to add my 'data-href'  value as variable in that popup window, that can be used as tool to take information from sql.. how to do that in proper way?

Comment: I have updated the code, please check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vishalj/gdVLs/3/ again ,following coded added their $('.ui-dialog-title').html(linkValue);

Comment: refreshed code, but code the same.. i need to import some data from sql into that popup dialog window. I need to pull data from sql by variable from url `data-href` value. For example `data-href=rsc10` so i can make variable `$i=rsc10` via ajax into that dialog window to pull some data from sql..

Comment: have you checked the following url ? jsfiddle.net/vishalj/gdVLs/3 as mentioned in above comment

Comment: now i saw that code. but its dialog title.. i need to put variable IN THAT dialog. I need to take some data from sql by that variable.. i need to pass variable from url into dialog window, using ajax. :) thats it.. how to do that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct JS source code is :

```
 $('.link').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
     var linkValue = $(this).attr('data-href');

     $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'details.php',
         data: 'i=' + linkValue,
         success: function (data) {
             $('#dialog-modal').html(data).dialog();
         }
     });
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: how is your answer any different to the code in the question?

Comment: The "e.preventDefault();" was missplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are created dynammically so event not attached with those elements

So try this

```
$(document).on('click','.link',function(e){

});
```